# Compute an ROC for a hybrid model where only one of the model components computes class probabilities

Tags: model, roc

I've created a hybrid model by taking an existing decision engine (TRUE/FALSE output) and supplementing it with a random forest classifier (TRUE/FALSE) model. The output of the hybrid model is produced by computing an OR from the predictions of the two models.

When evaluating the performance on historical data, I can produce a ROC for the random forest by computing the class probabilities based on the votes from all of the random trees combined. I cannot do this for the existing decision engine because it does not output probabilities. For the purpose of this analysis, I need to treat it as a black box.

**How can I compute an ROC for the hybrid model?** I would like to do this with R. I'm imagining that for each point on the ROC of the first model, I would need to compute the lift generated by adding the existing decision engine model.

Comment: I'm thinking that I can define the class probability of the hybrid model as 1 if the existing decision engine outputs `TRUE`, and equal to the random forest class probability if the existing decision engine outputs `FALSE`. Then I should see a lift in the ROC of the hybrid model as I've observed in the confusion matrix for the hybrid model compared to either model alone.

Answer (score 0):

A ROC models how you make decisions. They do assume a continous distribution (see https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/11293781/ ) but if you are combining two binary models then the most states you will have are 4, 3 if the two input models are given the same weight. It would make more sense to me to use a contingency table.

Comment: I’m combining one model with a binary output with another that has a continuous output for probability. So not exactly two binary models.

Comment: Ah, you describe combining them after reduction to a binary decision. Please update your question to make it clear what exactly you are doing